# Xamarin Get Webservices crash when not connected

Tags: web-services, xamarin.forms

i have a GET method to connect to a webservices in xamarin. The method works fine, but when my phone is not connected to internet, the application crash, i would like to know how to avoid this ?  Thanks for your answers:

```
 static public string GET(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
            using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // log errorText
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpWebRequest` throws an `Exception` if there is no internet connection.

You have handled the `Exception` using the catch block but there, you have also written `throw` which throws the exception again and if you haven't handled it into the calling method, your app will crash.

Either try removing `throw` from your catch block, or handle `Exception` again into a calling method.
Like

```
try
{
    var result = Get("myUrl");
}
Catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Handle it here too
}
```